# C# if statement to not to do something

Tags: c#, if-statement

I'm trying to write if statement to not to draw anything if "across" or "down" is less than or equal to zero. Not quite understand how to write it to stop draw_rect. Having problem as it still draws even though I have put down = 0

```
int horiz;
int vert;
int across;
int down;

char display_char;

void draw_rect ( void ) {

    //      If either of the width or height is less than or equal to zero,
    //      the function must not draw anything.


    draw_line( horiz, vert, across, vert, display_char );
    draw_line( horiz, down, across, down, display_char );
    draw_line( horiz, vert, horiz, down, display_char );
    draw_line( across, vert, across, down, display_char );

    if ( down > 0 ){
       ?????
    }   

int main( void ) {
    setup_screen();

    // draw a box.
    horiz = rand() % screen_width() / 2;
    vert = rand() % screen_height() / 2;
    across = 1 + rand() % (screen_width() - horiz - 1);
    down = 1 + rand() % (screen_height() - vert - 1);
    display_char = '@';
    draw_rect();
    show_screen();

    // draw a box with zero height.
    horiz = rand() % screen_width() / 2;
    vert = rand() % screen_height() / 2;
    across = 1 + rand() % (screen_width() - horiz - 1);
    down = 0;
    display_char = 'a';
    draw_rect();
    show_screen();




    timer_pause(5000);
    cleanup_screen();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Put the if before your draw line functions. So `if(YourConditionMeets) then draw;` and think of using [`DrawingContext.DrawRectangle Method`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingcontext.drawrectangle(v=vs.110).aspx) anyway

Comment: Also remember to add a closing brace for `draw_rect`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is simple:

```
void draw_rect ( void ) 
{

//If either of the width or height is less than or equal to zero,
//the function must not draw anything.

   if(across > 0 && down > 0)
   {
      draw_line( horiz, vert, across, vert, display_char );
      draw_line( horiz, down, across, down, display_char );
      draw_line( horiz, vert, horiz, down, display_char );
      draw_line( across, vert, across, down, display_char );
   }
}
```

Just think of it the other way around.